# Firefox zoom mechanic not working as intended?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using `zoom: 0.5;` and it is working fine on my site, but when I add `moz-transform: scale(0.5);` and `moz-transform-origin: 0 0;` To make the site Firefox compatible, the fixed positioned elements I have become unfixed and not placed in the correct place (to the top and left of where they should be). The site works as intended in chrome, and this only happens in Firefox.

Here is the code

```css
.mobPopUp{
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 900px;
    color: lime;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}
#mobPopUpBlue{
    right: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
html{
    zoom:0.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0
}
```

```html
<div id="mobPopUpred" class="mobPopUp">Right click on a mob to see their stats here</div>
```

**What am I doing wrong? And how can I have it so it works on Firefox as it does on Chrome with `zoom`**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a CSS `zoom` property, it's just a non-standard property invented by Internet Explorer and adopted by some other browsers for compatibility reasons. The correct property to use for scaling transformations is the `transform` property.

Firefox has long since remove the `-moz-` vendor prefix, and never implemented `zoom`, so that's probably why your code does nothing in Firefox, but for maxium browser support, you can use the below.

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
     -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5);
```

That will work in pretty much anything IE9 or better. If you need IE8 support, then you might try adding `zoom` in an IE <= 8 CSS hack.

Comment: Ok, but `transform: scale(0.5)` Has the same outcome. It dosent work. What can i do to fix my problem?

Comment: @icantmakegoodquestionsapparent Depends what the problem is. If you're expecting the layout changes that the non-standard zoom has, you will have to address that directly.